# Request Body issue in Spring Boot PUT Request

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am trying to create a PUT request where admin will be making decision based on some criteria and Verifying or Rejecting a user. I expect this decision in JSON body(Refer to Verification method in below image). But I am confused what json body should I send. I have sent the following JSON body { "REJECTED" }

{ REJECTED }
REJECTED

But everytime, it is returning false in the above method. Please help!!

[image]

Comment: What is the output for second println?
System.out.println(decision);

Comment: Can you paste the correct request json or edit your question with the correct json

Comment: I don't think `{ "REJECTED" }` is a valid JSON, it is not parseable to any object. You should specify the accepted content-type of the request, and in this case I guess a `text/plain` is enough (so your body would be simply `REJECTED` instead of `{ "REJECTED" }` ).

Comment: Hii, for first Sysout, its giving the complete JSON i am sending via postman, i,e. {REJECTED} or {"REJECTED"} or REJECTED. And its giving, false for the .equals method. I am unable to understand what is happening.

Comment: JSON is a notation to represent objects (basically pairs of property: value). You're not sending such an object but just a string value, so your request should be a text request, instead of a JSON request. Change the content type in Postman to `text` and simply send `REJECTED` (no curly brackets, no quote symbols).

Comment: @LuisIñesta thanks, it worked. Sending simple REJECTED worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any JSON here - your method type is void.
You need to return something maybe string or response itself.

Using System.out.println(), you are displaying the message on your console only but not sending a response to the server.